# Simple use of semaphore

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

It might be a stupid question to ask but I wanted to know that how semaphores work in Java. I have read many articles regarding it (on stackoverflow also) but could not get the idea of it.

Does not the predefined class Semaphore have any methods? Is it like we have to declare the object of it and write our own methods for the synchronization.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you not read the Javadoc for `Semaphore`? This is all clearly explained.

Comment: @chrylis The Javadoc is not the same as having it explained to you by another programmer. Why can't he ask a programming website about programming?

Comment: @doctordoder Asking a reasonable question is fine. "Doesn't this class have any methods" is trivial factual question answered instantly by reference to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

"A Semaphore is a thread synchronization construct that can be used either to send signals between threads to avoid missed signals, or to guard a critical section like you would with a lock" -[Source](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html)

A quick implimentation would be

```
public class Semaphore {
private boolean signal = false;

public synchronized void take() {
    this.signal = true;
    this.notify();
}

public synchronized void release() throws InterruptedException{
    while(!this.signal) wait();
       this.signal = false;
}

}
```

A tutorial and explanation for the Java 5+ implementation in the `java.util.concurrent` package [here.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/semaphore.html)